# Reading Office.context.mailbox.item.attachments in compose mode

Tags: office-js

I'm currently prototyping a small Outlook Add-in in which I'm able to retrieve most everything except attachments. (In compose mode)

Since Office.context.mailbox.item.attachments is always undefined in compose mode, I'd like to know if there is a way around this because I'd like to validate attachment name, type before sending the email.

Test environment:

- Project built with Yeoman generator-office
- Served with gulp serve-static locally
- Run in OWA

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far as I know the only way to get arbitrary attachments is via an EWS call (i.e. pass the appriopriate XML to [mailbox.makeEwsRequestAsync](https://dev.outlook.com/reference/add-ins/Office.context.mailbox.html#makeEwsRequestAsync)), which then requires the highest level of permission. To get the EWS ID you have to save the item using item.saveAsync.

"before sending the email" also may be problematic if you want this to happen automatically, there's no send event to hook into.

Comment: Thanks @Igaud for the lead on mailbox.makeEwsRequestAsync, Currently waiting for my sysadmin to provide the said permission. As for the "before sending the email". My prototype would require user to open the add-in for now and I hope the Office Team would quickly provide the necessary hooks, missing features and Cross-Platform support.

Comment: Just realized the permission is set in the Add-in manifest as <Permissions>ReadWriteMailbox</Permissions> and not as an Exchange MailBox permission. Source: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/docs/outlook/understanding-outlook-add-in-permissions.md